# Is using mock data across EVERY environment okay?

Tags: asp.net, mocking

Using mock data ensures each objects expected-behavior works as "expeceted"...I understand this!  And...I'm all for using mock data in local and deveopment (dev) environments...and somewhat agree with using mock data in the testing (test) environment.

However, we use mock data in EVERY environment...then end up scratching our heads when odd data from production creates issues.  I keep saying we need at least one environment to mimic production...but they "laugh & smirk" at the idea.

**We have mock data across the following environments:**

- LOCAL VM's (Virtual Machines)
- DEVELOPMENT Servers (Deveoplers come-together here with their VM code)
- TEST Servers (Testers hit this one)
- STAGING Servers (considered the 'acceptance' area)

**So my question is...**

**Q:** Should any of these environments contain production data?  If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

I could see a case being made for obfuscating any personal information (passwords, cc#'s and the like), but other than that I'd love to have live data to test against, at the very least by the time it gets to the staging step.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really about how sophisticated the mock data is or should be. If you are getting issues with production data, then you should think about extending your mock data sets with samples from the production data, especially the ones that are breaking your application.

Comment: Isn't extending mock-data with production data the same thing as replicating ACCEPTANCE from PRODUCTION?  Or...am I missing something.  I'm completely open to being wrong!